# previousyear and currentyear

Tags: sql

we have financial year Q4 for fy2018 going on presently

```
Q4 - Jan to Mar
Q3 - Apr to Jun
Q3 - Jul to Sep
Q1 - Oct to Dec
```

How can I write SQL for previous year when previous year is from 2017 Apr-2018 March and current year is from 2018 Apr - 2019 March

Comment: What you have tried yet? Where is your table structure details? Do we need to write a query that works for you without knowing about what you did or have?

Comment: and What's your DBMS ?